# C++ << >> operators

Tags: c++, operators, concatenation

I can use for example the `<<` operator to type my name as follows:

```
std::cout<<"My name is: "<<name<<std::endl;
```

On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) it mentions the following regarding `<<` and `>>`:

> In the context of iostreams, writers often will refer to `​<<` ​ and `​>>`​ as the “put-to” or "stream insertion" and “get-from” or "stream extraction" operators, respectively.

In the example code above, isn't the `<<` performing **concatenation**? Does **concatenation** have a special operator in C++?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing has got a *special* operator in C++. `std::ios` (its derived) *misused* `operator>>` and `operator<<` in order to provide a simple way to perform stream operation: those two operators have otherwise got a different semantics in C++.

An operator used to concatenate two `std::string` is `operator+` (but I think in this case they didn't *misuse* it: `operator+` between two strings is doing what I'd be expecting).

Comment: +1, it should also be noted that in this instance the `<<` operator returns the stream that was its 1st argument, which is what allows you to chain them.

Answer (score 1):

In this case concatenation isn't actually occurring. Instead, each of the strings are being written, in turn, to the output stream. In this case, that stream happens to be standard out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concatenating, you would use `operator +`. But as @tsellon says, your example is not, technically speaking, concatenation - it is writing sequentially into a stream. Maybe the difference seems abstract but the implications are very real.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of iostreams, `operator <<` inserts data into the stream. What the stream does with it is an entirely different story. It may concatenate strings (as is the case for [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/)), but it may also do something completely different.